# CheckBoxList check all by default yii

Tags: yii, checkboxlist

I'm using checkBoxList like so-

```
CHtml::checkBoxList('Interests', $selectedInterests, CHtml::listData($interests, 'interest_id','interest'), array('uncheckValue'=>'0',''checkAll' => 'Check all'));
```

I'm already utilising the option to have a 'check all' box, but I'd like all boxes to be checked by default when the user first comes to the page. They can then unCheck those that don't apply.

How can I have all boxes checked by default when the user first comes to the page using Yii's checkboxlist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass all the values of your checkBoxList in $selectedInterests as array.
I can't test it now but probably this should work:

```
CHtml::checkBoxList('Interests', CHtml::listData($interests, 'interest_id','interest_id'), CHtml::listData($interests, 'interest_id','interest'), array('uncheckValue'=>'0',''checkAll' => 'Check all'));
```

Taking a look at the source code of that method, you should return true in this line:

```
$checked=!is_array($select) && !strcmp($value,$select) || is_array($select) && in_array($value,$select);
```

Where $select is your $selectedInterest, and $value in your case are each of your 'interest_id' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`checkBoxList` have three parameters.

1. first parameter is field name
2. 2nd parameter is array of selected keys. This parameter makes the checkbox list selected.
3. 3rd parameter is array of options

Sample code:

```
$books = CHtml::listData(Book::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name');
$selected_keys = array_keys(CHtml::listData( $model->books, 'id' , 'id'));
echo CHtml::checkBoxList('Author[books][]', $selected_keys, $books);
```

More details are available in my blog post :
**[How to make Yii checkBoxList selected](http://scriptbaker.com/how-to-make-yii-checkboxlist-selected/)**